# My jump menu redirects me to the right pages, but doesn't show my jQuery dialog without quicky redirecting to a page not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, modal-dialog

I have a jump menu that has a few different options in it.  One option calls for a dialog to open, while the other two options redirect to other pages within the site.

I can only seem to get one of the two options to work at a time.  When I keep the onChange script the dialog opens, but then quickly redirects to a "page not found", but redirects to the pages properly.  When I remove the onChange script, the dialog opens fine, but the other options do not redirect me.

Can I have both working?

Here is my menu:

```
<select name="select_menu" size="1" class="select" onChange="if(this.selectedIndex!=0)
self.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
   <option selected="selected"><em>Options...</em></option>
   <option value="http://..1">Change Cat</option>
   <option class="bulkConfirmOpen">Approve</option> <!--dialog-->
   <option value="http://..2">Move to Cat</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is when you click the option that should open the dialog, the change script still tries to redirect to the page with the option's value as the url. In this case, the value of the option with the class "bulkConfirmOpen" has a value of "Approve." Which isn't a valid url.

There are a couple ways around this. You could avoid setting the location if the index is 2 (the index of the bulkConfirmOpen option), or probably better, check for the bulkConfirmOpen class before changing the location.

```
<select name="select_menu" size="1" class="select" onChange="if(this.selectedIndex!=0 && this.options[this.selectedIndex].className != 'bulkConfirmOpen')
self.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
   <option selected="selected"><em>Options...</em></option>
   <option value="http://..1">Change Cat</option>
   <option class="bulkConfirmOpen">Approve</option> <!--dialog-->
   <option value="http://..2">Move to Cat</option>
</select>
```